# Problems with navigation links when using include php statements

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, include, navigation

At present I am using an include statement to display all my menus. However I understand that some of my links are broken when accessing pages that are not located in the same directory.

Is there a way, by using the same link regardless of file location it will always access the same pages.

For example

My main folder currently contains:

```
Files = 
index.php
shop.php
mensTShirts.php

I also have the sub folders:

html
php
images
includes
css
items
```

The main problem I have is that from by using an include statement from to get the navBar from the html folder the links included do not work when a viewing a file from say the items folder.

So my question is to find out how to make the navigation links work for specific pages regardless of file location.

I hope you can understand my problem, I am also kind of new to this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you post an example link up here, with the path to the intended file? It's unclear whether a broken link 'foo.php' needs to bring up '/a_specific_dir/foo.php', /any_dir/foo.php or just /foo.php

Answer (score 0):

You should make config file to define your path. Then use the variable to include relative paths.